# pcap library not found!

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

```
 ./configure
 checking for gcc... gcc
 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
 checking for suffix of executables... 
 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
 checking for suffix of object files... o
 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
 checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
 checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
 checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
 error: pcap library not found!
```

[i have tried the commands ]

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libpcap0.8
[sudo] password for lester: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpcap0.8 is already the newest version (1.7.4-2).
libpcap0.8 set to manually installed.
libsqlite3-0 is already the newest version (3.11.0-1ubuntu1)
```

but still i caanot configure reaver

Comment: It's usually the **development** library that you need in these circumstances i.e. `libpcap-dev`

Comment: i did sudo apt-get install libcap-dev

Comment: and still the ./cnfigure didnt work

Comment: There's a suggestion [here](https://gitlab.com/billhibadb/reaver-wps/issues/97) that you may need to install `libsqlite3-dev` as well

Comment: @NitishMittal Note that you had a typo in "libcap-dev", it's "lib**p**cap0.8-dev" that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's the package `libpcap0.8-dev` that you're missing, which includes the appropriate symlink from `libpcap.so` to `libpcap.so.0.8`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030167/1543768) it's a Debian convention that the unversioned symlinks are part of the `-dev`-packages.